# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Red Hat server

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, redhat

I developed a JavaEE 7.0 Web Application using NetBeans (IDE) and GlassFish 4.1.0 (web server).

The application is working like a charm when I deploy it on the localhost. Now, I would like to deploy it on a Red Hat Enterprise Edition Linux Server 5.11 using GlassFish 4.1.0.

Therefore, I installed GlassFish on my Red Hat server and I followed these steps:

1. Opened GlassFish administration console and went to the "Applications" node:
   [image]
2. Clicked on the "Deploy" button and selected the war file (stored in the Red Hat server) of the application I wanted to deploy:
   [image]
3. Clicked on "Choose File". The following window appeared:
   [image]
4. My application needs some JAR files in order to work properly. All of them are saved in the following folder:
   [image]
5. Then I inserted all the paths in the "Libraries" entry of the GlassFish Administration Console:
   [image]
6. Deployed the application and restarted the NetBeans Server

However, each time I run my web application I get the following error:

```
[2016-07-08T21:20:15.226+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1468005611695] [timeMillis: 1468005615226] [levelValue: 1000] [[

  Exception during lifecycle processing

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specified library jar android-7.jar does not exist: /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/android-7.jar

    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.getAppLibs(DeploymentContextImpl.java:458)

    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:244)

    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createDeploymentClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:229)

    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:365)

    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)

    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)

    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)

    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)

    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)

    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

]]
```

I really do not understand what is going on, Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I inserted all the paths in the "Libraries" entry of the
>   GlassFish Administration Console:

You don't need to do this, I guess this is causing the problem.

Glassfish is searching for libs in the `lib` folder automatically, if this doesn't work you can also try the server global lib folder in `/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/lib`

If it still doesn't work there maybe a problem with the access rights, but on your screenshot it looks ok (world-readable).

Comment: Hi unwichtich, in fact it works like a charm. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate.